# Javascript: Grouping array elements

Tags: javascript

How do I turn a repeat number such as:

```
999117777774422111
```

Create output: //

```
 999, 11, 777777, 44, 22, 111
```

I basically want to separate the value when the digits change from the [i]th place.

Comment: Show the code you have written to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression like: `/(\d)\1*/g`.
`(\d)` means match any digit, `\1*` means match and of the initially matched digit.

```js
// Example:
'999117777774422111'.match(/([0-9])\1*/g)

 // Output:
 // ["999", "11", "777777", "44", "22", "111"]
    
 console.log('999117777774422111'.match(/([0-9])\1*/g));
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not really sorting but more like comparing.

**Here is a solution**:

```js
var str = "999117777774422111";
var out = str[0];

for (var i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] == str[i-1]) {
    out += str[i];
  } else {
    out += ", " + str[i];
  }
}

console.log(out);
```

---

**Or sending the output as array:**

```js
var str = "999117777774422111";
var out = [str[0]];

var j = 0;

for (var i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] != str[i-1]) {
    j++;
    out[j] = "";
  }
  
  out[j] += str[i];
}

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
let num='999117777774422111';
let result=num.match(/(\d)\1*/g);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answers zeropublix. You more or less made life much easier.